# How to filter observable from google firestore

Tags: angular, observable

I'm using observable from firestore to fill select list

```
getInvoices() {
this.invCollection = this.afs.collection('invoices');
this.invoices = this.invCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  shareReplay(1),
  map(actions => {
  return actions.map(action => ({
    key: action.payload.doc.id,
    ...action.payload.doc.data()
  }))
})
)

this.invList = this.invoices.source;
```

}

And I share data from this.inv observable with this.invList observable

I would like to filter secondone observable based on user selection

```
<mat-form-field class="ffield">
    <mat-select (selectionChange)="getInv($event)" placeholder="Choose invoice">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let invoice of invoices | async; trackBy: trackByFn" [value]="invoice.key">{{invoice.invNo}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>


getInv(e) {
  this.sID = e.value; //id of selected invoice

  //TODO filter this.invList observable   }
```

I need help with filtering this.invList observable

I did tried something like

```
this.invList.pipe(map(aaa => {return aaa.map(bbb => ())}), filter(flt => flt.key === this.sID)).subscribe(sss => (console.log(sss.invNo)))
```

but its not working, property key does not exist

Comment: what is flt here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rxjs `filter` operator filter values in the stream (your array is a single value in stream), in your case you don't need filter values in stream, you need `map` array of values to specific value by ID.

```
this.invoices$ = this.invCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(actions => 
    actions.map(action => 
      ({
        key: action.payload.doc.id,
        ...action.payload.doc.data()
      })
    )
  )
)
```

if you need to create stream with element by specific id:

```
getInvoiseById(id): Observable<InvoiceType> {
 return this.invoices$.pipe(
   map(invoices => 
     invoices.filter(({key}) => key === id)))
   )
}
```

if you need to create stream with active invoice, better way is create stream with active ID and combine it with invoice's stream

```
activeId$ = new Subject<TypeOfIdField>();

activeInvoice$ = combineLatest([
  this.invoices$,
  this.activeId$
]).pipe(
  map(([invoices, id]) => 
    invoices.find(({key}) => key === id)
  )
)

setActiveId(id) {
  this.activeId$.next(id);
}
```

Notice: If you want use `shareReplay`, better move it to the end of pipeline, in your code you first cache your initial data and after that map it to used format, in this case you transform the data for every subsription, if you move `shareReplay` to the end of pipeline, you cache already transformed data

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My first thought while reading your answer was This is so obvious and logicall but then i tried to use getInvoiseById(id) function and That’s not working and i can’t see why. How should i use that function

Comment: `getInvoiseById` it's good choice if you ID is static, then you create stream with elements filtered by the ID and you can use it with async pipe or whatever you want

Comment: can you describe your requirements (use case)?

Comment: I’m using Observable from Firestore to fill Select list, - this.invoices. I’m already using async pipe for that. Select list is suplied with inv id and inv number. When user select one of invoices the Text fields below should be filled with coresponding data. So i wanted to filter observable this.invoices by inv id because it contains all data i need and fill form fields

Comment: Better use `combineLatest` with `activeId$` stream, it's allow you to get active invoice in single stream. If you use `getInvoiseById`, you create new stream for each ID